# ImageMagick: Distort and Overlay

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have several pictures of a landscape.
Using the ImageMagick CLI on OSX, I would like to distort and overlay them properly.
I have looked for distortion coordinates between several of the pictures and a reference picture. I fail to understand the diference between `-distort` and `+distort` and how it plays with `+repage`. When I use `-distort`, the output has the desired offset but it's incomplete (it needs to be bigger). When I use `+distort`, I get the full image but it's missing the offset.
Reading the documentation I understand that I could do without the offset if I did the overlay composition in the same command before the offset information is lost but what's happening is that the distort is being applied to both the reference and the distorted images.

This is the result of using `-distort`:
[image]

This is the result of using `+distort`:
[image]

The offset of the `-distort` result would work once I apply it as an overlay (here using the `composite` in a separate command, but it's missing a big chunk of the picture.
[image]

When I tried to consolidate it in a single command this is the result I get:
[image]

This is the command I'm currently using:

```
convert base.jpg overlay.jpg
 -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '961,1695 1856,2461   2279,1520 3185,2303   3564,2173 4441,2970   1547,2817 2441,3594'
 -compose blend -define compose:args=50,100 -composite result.jpg
```

I understand I could use parenthesis there but I fail to see where should I put them.

Thanks!

**Update:** this is the result of the overlay when using `+distort` either in two steps or in a single step as recommended by Mark.
[image]

Comment: Note that base.jpg is a grayscale picture with a large white border, sufficient to include all the other pictures. The black border in the last picture is due to `transparent` not being supported in `jpg`.

Comment: From what I remember +distort extends the canvas to hold the distorted image if it extends past the current canvas. -distort will cut off the image if it extends past the current canvas.

Comment: @Bonzo that is exactly how I read the documentation and it does in fact extend the canvas so the whole image is saved but additionally it trims away the offset that I actually need to properly overlay the images afterwards. If I could keep that offset that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `-flatten` instead of `-composite`.

```
convert base.jpg \( b.jpg -matte -virtual-pixel transparent +distort Perspective '961,1695 1856,2461   2279,1520 3185,2303   3564,2173 4441,2970   1547,2817 2441,3594' \) -compose blend -define compose:args=100,50 -flatten result.jpg
```

Turns out that `-composite` ignores the image offsets whereas `-flatten` works with layers and uses the offset information.

The suggestion came from this thread: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20157

This is the documentation to `flatten` (link broken in the discussion above): http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#flatten

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the issues, but would suggest you try this (untested):

```
convert base.jpg \ 
   \( overlay.jpg -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '961,1695 1856,2461   2279,1520 3185,2303   3564,2173 4441,2970   1547,2817 2441,3594' \) \
   -define compose:args=50,100 -compose blend -composite result.jpg
```

That would mean that the perspective distortion is only applied to the overlay, not the base. So, in the code above, the first line only processes the base image, the second line only processes the overlay, and the final line blends the two.

Comment: Thanks. That works as if I ran two separate commands and still either "crops" or "resets" the offset. It's like the `+repage` option is being applied by default when I use `+distort` but I cannot see how to explicitly disable it. I added an additional result of running your command using `+distort`